# How can I use Sliver Overlord to find non-Slivers?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I have [Sliver Overlord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSliver%20Overlord%5d) as my commander. Is there a combo that will let me search for non-Sliver combo cards using [Sliver Overlord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSliver%20Overlord%5d)? Id like to be able to use [Sliver Overlord](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSliver%20Overlord%5d) to find said card/ cards as well

Comment: Can you be more specific in what your problem is? You want to use Sliver Overlord to find which particular cards?

Comment: Ok to be honest im trying to search for Paradox engine using sliver overlord i found a plan to do so but i confused Mirror Entity's bottom ability and am looking for a replacement this was my idea Mirror Entity, Zur the Enchanter, Intruder Alarm or id look for March of the Machines thin Paradox engine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 cards that allow you to search for non-sliver cards as if they were slivers: [Arcane Adaptation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArcane%20Adaptation%5d) and [Conspiracy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bConspiracy%5d).

The first can add the sliver type to creature cards you own (and control), and the second sets the creature type of creature cards you own (and control).

Comment: Was just about to post these same 2 cards. Still working with gatherer search to see if there are any others.

Comment: A less efficient way could also be Artificial Evolution, which you can use to change the word "sliver" to a different creature type

Comment: Thanks but how would i search for the enchantment with sliver overlord or is there not a way?

Comment: Ok to be honest im trying to search for Paradox engine using sliver overlord i found a plan to do so but i confused Mirror Entity's bottom ability and am looking for a replacement this was my idea Mirror Entity, Zur the Enchanter, Intruder Alarm or id look for March of the Machines thin Paradox engine

Comment: You will not be able to search for Paradox Engine because it is not a creature. I don't think there's any way to search for a non-Creature with Sliver Overlord. But there are plenty of other cards you could put in your deck that would allow you to search for Paradox Engine.

Comment: March of the machines fixes that

Comment: @KCkingcollin March of the Machines doesn't help you, because it only affects artifacts on the battlefield.  Permanents that aren't in play are "[type] *cards*" rather than having the type itself, and aren't effected by things like March of the Machines unless the card specifically mentions [type] cards like Conspiracy and Arcane Adaptation do.  I recommend Hoarding Dragon instead.

Comment: Well that just sucks thanks for the recommendation thogh

Comment: Update: Maskwood Nexus makes all your creatures, creature spells, and creature cards you own every creature type (including sliver)